# How can I reuse the index method in rails passing multiple parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, angularjs, routes

I'm doing my project which is I used the rails-api gem and angularjs. My concern is I saw some tutorial which is the index method of controller can recieve different paramater and render the json result. So, I tried in using the DHC and Postman to pass different paramaters but I got a 404 not found error.

```
localhost:3000/vendormine/index?exp=Beach&city_address=Lapasan City&est_guest=30
```

controller.rb

```
def index
  venue = Venue.all
  if params[:exp]
    experience = Experience.find(params[:exp])
    venue = experience.venues.base_filter(params[:city_address], params[:est_guest])
  end
  render json: venue, status: :ok
end
```

routes.rb

```
resources :vendormines
```

Comment: that url isn't URL safe. Try just something simple: `localhost:3000/vendormine/index?exp=test_string`

Comment: what do mean test_string? can you give some clear example. sorry I'm new rails api. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You get 404 because there is no route corresponding to `localhost:3000/vendormine/index` in your app.

Try `localhost:3000/vendormines?exp=Beach&city_address=Lapasan City&est_guest=30`.

`resources :vendormines` creates the following routes. You need to access `/vendormines` to invoke the index action of VendorminesController.

```
        vendormines GET      /vendormines(.:format)                 vendormines#index
                    POST     /vendormines(.:format)                 vendormines#create
     new_vendormine GET      /vendormines/new(.:format)             vendormines#new
    edit_vendormine GET      /vendormines/:id/edit(.:format)        vendormines#edit
         vendormine GET      /vendormines/:id(.:format)             vendormines#show
                    PATCH    /vendormines/:id(.:format)             vendormines#update
                    PUT      /vendormines/:id(.:format)             vendormines#update
                    DELETE   /vendormines/:id(.:format)             vendormines#destroy
```

You can see the routes of your app by executing `rake routes` in the terminal.

Comment: Thank you sir. I found out that my controller name was in singular form. btw, I already change it. My question now how can I reuse my index method with  different paramater to pass. Not just like the default query of all data in venue.

Comment: You don't have to do anything special. If 'localhost:3000/vendormines' correctly routes to your VendorminesController#index, then 'localhost:3000/vendormines?exp=Beach&city_address=Lapasan City&est_guest=30` also routes you to the same index action. The get parameters you added in the url are stored in params.